# In windows 11 how do I stop programs from hiding the task bar

Tags: windows

Programs are not in full screen, and after a reboot issue is fixed, but then it does it again where Chrome is normally the fist covers the taskbar, how can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Open an app, move the app so it does not cover the task bar and save it.  If Windows 10, change the scale, restart, change the scale back.  That sometimes helps.